# Make a column UNIQUE with multiple column check

Tags: mysql

i am trying to create a MySQL table with name `tbl_users`. In which i have 2 columns `mobile` and `altmobile`, from these two columns i would like to make sure none of the `Mobile number` is repeated. Each number should be unique in both the column and should check from both the column before inserting into the table.

**Is it possible to do?**

I am new in these advance stuff. Rather then doing it on a server-side language (PHP) i want to handle this on database level itself, because this table will have more then 500k rows. So to make sure the process will run faster i would like to do it on database level itself.

Suppose i have a number `236463646` this number should be check in both the column `mobile` and `mobilealt` so the same number entry can not get reenter into the database.

Here is how my table structure looks like:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you plan on ever updating both numbers at once, or will it always be one or the other?

Comment: Most of the time i will be updating one or other. If you want i can share my database table structure.

Comment: I believe the solution for you would be write a trigger BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE. You can get more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: You can create composite unique index over both columns.

Comment: @mitkosoft how can i do this? Any example?

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel i have never worked with trigger before.

Comment: @user3201500, I saw your requirement, index will not help in that case, you definitely need a trigger for that.

Comment: Ok new i have to understand how can i do this. Any suggestions how can i create trigger so a number can not be duplicate in either of the column?

Comment: @mitkosoft yes i tried index as per your previous answer and its not helping.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the mobile numbers in one column on a separate table and reference them from the users table. This way you can easily apply a unique constraint on the mobile numbers column.

Comment: Even if it does not directly answer the question, that's the best approach here. A table like (userId, phoneType, phoneValue) would handle the job.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can write a trigger like below. This trigger is configure to be activated before the insert on the table occurs and check in a IF statement if the 2 mobile fields are equal. If they are, the system will throw an exception that will stop the insert process.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER unique_email BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_users
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     DECLARE msg varchar(255); 
     IF new.mobile = new.altmobile THEN
        SET msg = 'The mobile number must be unique.' 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg; 
     END IF;
  END;
|
```

Also, please read this material to understand the concept and how to implement: [mysql triggers tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx).

Comment: Can you explain why the OP would "try this". just showing a block of code isn't very helpful - what have you changed, and why does it make the process work? Cheers